# I have ten buttons, I need to know which button the user has selected and save that information to the users profile

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton, xcode7

Ok so I have been trying to figure this out for ages to no avail!!!

I have a list of 10 buttons, the user picks 1 of these buttons and I need to save that result to my users profile which is on a different View Controller. I was trying to put the buttons in an array but was not able to. Any help would be appreciated, I am very new to swift and xcode!

I tried adding them to a outlet collection but it didn't work either.

```
 var genreArray = ["rockGenreButton", "bluesGenreButton","funkGenreButton", "indieGenreButton", "metalGenreButton", "popGenreButton", "altGenreButton","electronicGenreButton", "countryGenreButton", "tradGenreButton"]
```

Above is the array I created I am lost on which step to take next how do I call which [0] of the array was selected and save to currentUser?

Sorry if this is a really stupid question but I can't find a relevant answer anywhere!

Comment: Ten buttons. Ten separate functions. Why make them all run the same action? Make it easy for yourself.

Comment: Add tags to each button . addTarget to a single method and find out which button is selected using the button tag.

Comment: The user selects a button and you want to save the data. It sounds like you should have a tableView of the list of options and when you select a cell then the delegate method "did select row at index path" will be called and you can extract the data you want. From here you should have a user model stored somewhere either in core data or maybe a global one or maybe just an application wide variable stored in app delegate. Then you just access that one model. I don't really know what your setup looks like but it seems like you might need to refactor a bit. Do not use outlet Collections for this.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help got it sorted with the add tag answer. You're probably right with the refactoring!!! Ya I used outlet collections and had to spend about an hour figuring out why my app was crashing!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add button tag and find which button has been clicked.

[image]

once you have created outlet for all buttons (same function)

```
    @IBAction func btnClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(sender.tag.description)

    }
```

*just ctrl click each button to same action*

to get the tag of the pressed button

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thanks very much thats what I was looking for!

Comment: Very happy to help!! please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: No. Why do people insist on doing this? It's possibly the worst way... no, it IS the worst way to approach this. You have ten buttons. Create a function for each. You should NEVER use tags.

Comment: Ugh, this is terrible. :(

Comment: @Fogmeister Please let us know why is it terrible. We sure are newbies to swift

Comment: I concur with @vinbhai4u I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting for me to do?

Comment: This is not something new to Swift. This is the whole idea of using the `tag` property of `UIView`. It creates lazy design. State and data should never be stored in views. That's not what they are for. There is always a much better way of doing this. The simplest of which is to create separate functions for each button.

Comment: @Grace I've added an answer. Sorry to be so negative about this but it is something that has continued to prevail in iOS development for years and it just encourages bad design. Hopefully my answer will help to show you what else you can do and why other approaches are much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tag` property of views encourages lazy/bad design in software. It is storing data in views.

Not only that but how is any other developer (including yourself in 6 months time) going to know what `if(btn.tag == 4)` actually means? It hides the actual purpose of what you're doing.

One of the simplest ways to do something like this in a much better design approach is to create separate functions. One for each button. There is no reason for all your buttons to run the same function.

The first improvement would be to have functions like `buttonOnePressed`, `buttonTwoPressed` and so on.

```
@IBAction func buttonOnePressed {
    // do something
}
```

Again though you are hiding the actual meaning of your app.

You could give them names like...

```
@IBAction func rockGenreButtonTapped {
    // do something
}

@IBAction func bluesGenreButtonTapped {
    // do something
}
```

That's much better. I now know just by looking at the function when it will run.

Maybe a better approach is to name the function as to what it's actually going to do...

```
@IBAction func showRockGenreDetails {
    // present Rock Genre screen
}

@IBAction func showBluesGenreDetails {
    // present Blues Genre screen
}
```

This time I not only know that it's an action (IBAction) I also know just by reading the function name what it is going to be doing.

As was mentioned in the comments. You could also do things like using a `UITableViewController` to present a list of genres. This is actually a much better approach than what I have shown here but is much more difficult to explain easily.

Comment: Hi @Fogmeister thanks for your very detailed answer, much appreciated. However and maybe I'm wrong..... I think what Vinbhai4u suggests works creating tags on btns. I had already created buttons like ye suggested   "@IBAction func bluesGenreButton {  }"Maybe my original post was unclear I posted the array method I thought was needed to ID each btn so apologies! Tagging each btn ID's which button is clicked. However I now understand what you were saying above to make 10 diff btns with the same function ya and ID them that way? Sorry still a lot to learn but thank you for your help!